# Is the phrase "With regards to the test requirement, John will need it spelling out" grammatically correct?

Tags: tenses

Or should the phrase be "...John will need it spelled out"?
Or is it the case that both phrases are grammatically correct?

Comment: With "regard" to the test requirement, John will need to spell it out-- this looks better, doesn't it?

Comment: It does, but that changes the meaning of the statement: rather than John needing somebody else to spell the requirement out, John is now the one spelling the requirement out.

Comment: Absenting any context, one could hardly tell who needs to do the "spelling out" because it is not implicit in the supplied information. Now that you have added an extra bit, you could paraphrase it thus-- With regard to the test requirement, John will need to have it spelt out (by someone).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. So, although unconventional, "it" could refer to the "requirement" and therefore the sentence in the title can be considered grammatically correct?

Comment: Sorry, "it" refers to the "test requirement". Nothing unconventional there. But I would still prefer writing-- "With regard to the test requirement, John will need to have it spelt out." (If someone else has to do the "spelling out" on behalf/order of John).

Comment: The version in the title doesn't work, and that has nothing to do with the use of 'it' (which is nothing special). There is just no way "spelling" fits in there, it should indeed be spelled / spelt.

Comment: ...John will need it spelled out.

Comment: @weenoid *John will need it spelled out* is more idiomatic by far. I'm struggling to come up with an interpretation where the *spelling* version would actually make sense. I'll also add that you should not change it to *John will need **it spelled** out*, because that definitely *does* change the meaning. (Which might be okay, if you want a different meaning, but most likely isn't okay.)

Comment: @weenoid You can say that the test requirement will need spelling out, but not that John will need it spelling out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the *-ing* form grammatically correct?   Yes.   Is it sensible?   No.

> John will need [the requirement] spelled out.

Here, the so-called past participle carries passive semantics.   Something (although we have no idea what) spells that requirement out.   The modificand "it" is the *patient* of the verb "spelled".   "John" is its *target* or *beneficiary* or *recipient*.

> * John will need [the requirement] spelling out.

Here, the so-called present participle carries active semantics.   There is no explicit patient for "spelling", and the requirement is the agent.

A requirement could be a sensible agent.   For example, a requirement might spell out a specific method, or an entire procedure, or some other course of action.   Another requirement might spell out a set of constraints.

Grammatically, it's not so sensible to have a requirement spell out some unspecified patient.   The transitive verb is missing an object, and nothing in this context makes that missing object sensible.

Culturally, it's not sensible to assume that the test requirement will change to suit John's needs.   We can easily assume that John must satisfy the requirement, but not so easily assume that this requirement is intended to satisfy him.

The requirement is a grammatically possible agent, but it isn't a sensible agent in the assumed context and for the assumed purpose.   What is sensible in this context is the requirement as a patient.   Someone will need to spell the requirement out for John, although we don't much care who does it.   Regarding the test requirement, John will need it spelled out.

Answer (score -1):

I believe this to be clear, unambiguous and understandable. There are many such constructs. Here are two. Thinking of my aching tooth, I will need it pulling out. To understand the logic, we will need it setting out.

To take your example, I think this conventional construct has implied content as shown by my parentheses “... requirement, John will need it (in a state of being ) spelled out (for him).“ Similar implication applies to my own two examples.

There is no ambiguity in the convention, which clearly identifies “it” with the preceding noun or noun phrase (test requirement, aching tooth, logic) and not with John, I or we.

Comment: Neither of your examples are correct as far as I'm aware. It should be 'pulled out' and 'set out' or 'to have it pulled out' and 'to have it set out'.

Comment: The correct version of your comment is “neither ... is correct”. There is no question that the original construct is understandable and in common use. We clearly inhabit different linguistic worlds, as does the person who marked the answer down.

Comment: None of your examples sound correct to me either; I don't think I've ever heard the active participle used with passive meaning like that. Is that construct used in print? If so, I would like an example giving. (The grammar of my last sentence is deliberately ironic, of course.)